# Is there a function to get n out of m elements of a list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I want for example 8 out of 10 (or 80%) elements of a list to simulate a penetration rate of a market with python 2.7. The list changes dynamically in sense of that it gets appendings in every simulation step. Therefore it needs to follow a rule that old elements stay always the same and the new get filtered in the same way. And the filter should somehow be distributed, so that not just the last 20 out of 100 elements of a list gets removed.

I already found out, that I can get every nth element of a list with [::n] but unfortunately this is limited to max 50% of elements of the list.

If I have a list like `my_list=[1,2,3,...,20]` and I want 80% of list values like `my_list_eighty_percent=[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19]`. In the next simulation step for example ten new vehicles got in the road network and the list is now my_list=[1,2,3,...,30]. Now the result should look like my_list_eighty_percent=[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,29].

But the sequence is not important as long as it follows always the same rule.

Comment: `my_list[0:n]` ??

Comment: So you want to take a [`random` `sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) from a given population?

Comment: from a given population. But the population (vehicles) change dynamicilly, because the list gets permanently appendings.

Answer (score 2):

Try;

```
n = int(len(my_list) * 0.8)
new_list = my_list[0:n]
```

Comment: here you get always the nth first items.

Comment: I suggest to convert n to int before slicing, otherwise exception is raised

Comment: This works but I want to do it for vehicles in a road network and then I have always the last 20 vehicles, which have not the device.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
from random import sample
sample(my_list, int(len(my_list)*0.8))
```

As example:

```
>>> l = list(range(100))
>>> from random import sample
>>> sample(l, 15)
[20, 1, 28, 6, 97, 33, 81, 22, 52, 91, 24, 46, 86, 39, 61]
>>> sample(l, int(len(l)*0.3))
[65, 41, 96, 27, 81, 87, 32, 10, 21, 49, 60, 5, 31, 52, 74, 11, 71, 25, 76, 38, 44, 29, 58, 73, 19, 42, 4, 61, 24, 79]
```

Comment: This would work as long as the list stay always the same, but my list gets permanently appendings. And the function is used in every simulation step. So If use the random function, I have different elements in every simulation step.